# Only integer in HTML input form, type number doesn't work

Tags: html, forms

I have a website with a calculation model: http://073design.nl/kasopmaak/kasopmaak2.html

here I want people only to enter INTEGER numbers, so I added step="1' to the input html form field. However it's still possible toi enter FLOATS.

Does someone know, why the step="1" is not working here?

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" id="in01" placeholder="0" name="amount_0.10">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that decimals must be 0. So i would use:

```
<input type="number" step="1.00" class="form-control" id="in01" 
placeholder="0" name="amount_0.10">
```

Value "1" for step is the default one

Answer (score 0):

The restriction (`type = "number"`) is only checked when the form is submitted.

If you want to disallow inputting anything but numbers, you'll have to add an `onkeypress` event listener to the `input` and filter out non-number characters. The user can still paste arbitrary text, so you also have to add an event listener for `blur` and keep the focus on the `input` if it does not contain a valid integer.

---

Here's the handler, courtesy of your mom and ChatGPT:

`<input type="number" step="1" onkeypress="return onlyDigits(event)">`

```
function onlyDigits(event) {
  var key = event.key;
  var pattern = /\d/;
  return pattern.test(key) || isControlKey(event);
}
function isControlKey(event) {
  return (
    event.key === 'Backspace' ||
    event.key === 'Delete' ||
    event.key === 'ArrowLeft' ||
    event.key === 'ArrowRight' ||
    event.key === 'ArrowUp' ||
    event.key === 'ArrowDown' ||
    event.key === 'Tab'
  );
}
```